# how to get the value of element that created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am working on API and this HTML code created dynamically

```
 <li  class="d-flex align-item-center  movieId">
                     
    <a class=" d-flex w-100" data-mov="${res[i].id}">             
      <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${res[i].poster_path}" class="img-fluid himg" 
       alt="${res[i].title}" style="width:60px; height:70px">

        <p class=" p-3"> ${res[i].title}</p>
     </a>
              
  </li>
```

I want when I click on the `<a>` tag I get the `data-mov` attribute value... I did solve it but when I click on any elements inside the `<a>` like `<img>` and `<p>` the `data-mov` value did not get. However, these elements inside it.

this is what I am trying to do

```
 $(".srearchResults ul").on("click", "a", function (event) {

       
        let id = event.target.getAttribute("data-mov");

        console.log(id);

        //$(this).find("a").data("mov");
        //$(this).find("a").attr("data-mov");
});
```

The two lines commented I used and get undefined. When clicking on `<p>` or `<img>` i get null what would be the solution for that?

Comment: what does "a" do in your on click?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: `let id = $(this).data("mov");`

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` to get the element the listener is attached to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JavaScript solution:

```js
const ulElement = document.querySelector("ul");

ulElement.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  let element = e.target;
  let liElement;

  while (element && element.nodename !== "UL") {
    if (element.nodeName === "LI") {
      liElement = element;
    }
    element = element.parentElement;
  }

  const anchor = liElement.querySelector('a');

  console.log(anchor.dataset.mov);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-mov="data-mov-1">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="100">
      <p>1</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-mov="data-mov-2">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="100">
      <p>2</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `event.target` it'll select the element you click on not the `a` and while `img` and `p` doesn't have `data-mov` it will output null or undefined ..  so you need to use `let id = $(this).data("mov");` instead .. no need to use `.find('a')` because `$(this)` will select the `a` for you and no nested `a` inside the clicked `a`

This is how your code work [data-mov added to the img] so when you click on the img you'll get the `data-mov` of the img

```js
let res = [
  {
    'id' : 1,
    'poster_path' : 234,
    'title' : 'anything'
  },

]

$('ul').append(`<li  class="d-flex align-item-center  movieId">
                     
    <a class=" d-flex w-100" data-mov="${res[0].id}">             
      <img data-mov="image data mov" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${res[0].poster_path}" class="img-fluid himg" 
       alt="${res[0].title}" style="width:60px; height:70px">

        <p class=" p-3"> ${res[0].title}</p>
     </a>
              
  </li>`);
  
$("ul").on("click", "a", function (event) {


      let id = event.target.getAttribute("data-mov");

      console.log(id);

      
      //$(this).find("a").attr("data-mov");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

And this is how it should work

```js
let res = [
  {
    'id' : 1,
    'poster_path' : 234,
    'title' : 'anything'
  },

]

$('ul').append(`<li  class="d-flex align-item-center  movieId">
                     
    <a class=" d-flex w-100" data-mov="${res[0].id}">             
      <img data-mov="image data mov" src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${res[0].poster_path}" class="img-fluid himg" 
       alt="${res[0].title}" style="width:60px; height:70px">

        <p class=" p-3"> ${res[0].title}</p>
     </a>
              
  </li>`);
  
$("ul").on("click", "a", function (event) {


      let id = $(this).data('mov');

      console.log(id);

      
      //$(this).find("a").attr("data-mov");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: The fact that it's unclear how `event.currentTarget` works with jQuery's delegate listeners is another reason to once and for all stop using jQuery.